# Is it possible to use an RPi as a local server (I think it would be considered that) for your PC, but all local -- no internet connection?

Tags: raspbian, file-server

I have html files that have a bunch of javascript animations in them. When you open the files locally on your PC, the animations run. When it runs these animations, it takes up some of the total CPU usage. The issue is that when I am using these animations, I am already pressed for CPU usage.

I am wondering if there is any way to have these files on a Pi, connect it to my PC somehow, and have the ability to open and view the files on the PC (almost as if it were a server), all while the Pi is taking the CPU hit. The catch is that I need to be able to do this with no internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do but you will gain nothing on it because javascript on a html page will always run on the client.

Comment: OH! Well then you're absolutely right, that wouldn't help. I'm not sure why, but I was under the impression the JavaScript was run server side... But after a bit of research, you're right!